# How do you handle subscription confirmation links in Django?

Tags: python, django

In my application, when people sign up, they just enter their email adress.
a User is created in Django, and the "is_confirmed" field is set to False.

Just after this, I'd like to send to the new user an email with a link to click.
That link should allow this new user to enter complementary information, and choose a password before definitive sign up.

The questions are:

- how to generate these links in Django? (I suppose these links should be unique and kind of secured sothat no one can "guess" the URL)
- Where do you trigger the mail sending? (signals? `save()`user method? Other?)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to handle User Authentication yourself instead of using library such as [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or others?

Comment: Nope, I didn't take a look to these libs for now because I didn't see the need. Do you think these libs can help in generating confirmation links?

Comment: Yes, they completely handle it for you. Most of them also handle things like password reset and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look to Python-social-auth which look promising. (https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at something like [django-invitation](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-invitation/wiki/Home) for an example of how this is often done. They describe the standard generate key/send email/visit unique URL scheme that I think you want. They do use a post-save hook on the model to send the email as you mentioned.

As for generating the key, see the [models.py](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-invitation/src/127ac49785f6e28303b4b996359d5776f7016213/invitation/models.py?at=default) file where they do something like this:

```
salt = sha_constructor(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
key = sha_constructor("%s%s%s" % (datetime.datetime.now(), salt, user.username)).hexdigest()
```

Hope that helps!